# How to slice datetime64 based index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I am pretty sure it is a simple question, but I just don't work as expect.
Given the following data frame:

```
request_date   deal_id  
20180428       00812342
20180428       12341234
20180428       43213412
20180428       12341234
20180428       34323432
... ...
20210506       16674900
```

I want to just slice one quarter let say all entries for 2019-03-01 to 2019-03-31 and then create a histogram.

I tried to slice it with strings or .loc but neither ways seems to work..

```
df_date['20190301':'20190305']

KeyError: "Cannot get left slice bound for non-unique label: '20190301'"
```

Comment: What is your pandas version? For me working well in pandas `1.2.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you are missing any of the below steps.

```
df['request_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.request_date, format='%Y%m%d')
df = df.set_index('request_date')
df.loc['20180428':'20180429'] ## preferable
df['20180428':'20180429']
```

**Output**

```
            deal_id
request_date    
2018-04-28  812342
2018-04-28  12341234
2018-04-28  43213412
2018-04-28  12341234
2018-04-28  34323432
```

Comment: Great, all the best!